# Does disabling a submit button with a click event handler prevent it from submitting?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I had some an html button that was used for submitting a form:

```
<input id="myButton" value="למפה שלי" xclass="MustField fc_button" type="submit" style="width:100%;">
```

but since it was doing double submits when people where (I assume) double clicking it, I added the following code:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // disable the button
    this.disabled = true;

    // re-enable the button after 5 seconds
    setTimeout(function(button) {
        button.disabled = false;
    }, 5000, this);  // 5000 milliseconds = 5 seconds
});
</script>
```

and it worked for several weeks or even months...

suddenly today, the form stopped submitting...
After looking around I decided to change the script block to look like this:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // disable the button
    //this.disabled = true;
    //addint the above line ended up in preventing the form from bein submitted.
    setTimeout(function(button) {
        button.disabled = true;
    }, 50, this);  // 50 milliseconds

    // re-enable the button after 5 seconds
    setTimeout(function(button) {
        button.disabled = false;
    }, 5000, this);  // 5000 milliseconds = 5 seconds
});
</script>
```

and it resolved the issue.

My Q is - how can this be ...
Did some breaking change happen recently?
or could this be the result of something else that triggered this issue and my solution was able to surpass it even though the issue was somewhere else?

This whole issue is happening as part of a wordpress site using elementor and quite a lot of code.

Comment: It's just a bad strategy (and a bad UX). Forget about the button and work with the form's `submit` event. Disable the button only if you want to convey to the user that the form is not complete and ready to submit.

Comment: That is the typical solution, surprised it was not happening before. You probably would be better off disabling it via the submit action and not disabling the button.

Comment: @isherwood Why is this bad UX? If you don't want them to submit again, disabling the submit button conveys that perfectly. An additional strategy is to display a loading indicator as a model that prevents interacting with the form at all.

Comment: Because it's reenabled 5 seconds later for no reason. If it's disabled it should be for a data-driven reason, not an arbitrary timeout.

Comment: What should happen? Should the form just submit to at URL in the action attribute of the form or will you handle the submit event in JavaScript, do something to the page or make a AJAX request?